# What's the difference between "revisions" and "suggestions"?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, revisions-list

In user's profile, there is [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham?tab=activity&sort=revisions) and [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). I see the two lists are all about revisions and edits. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of suggestions includes all edits you **suggested**, including those that were not made (i.e., were rejected).

The list of revisions includes all edits you **made**, including those that were not suggestions (i.e., edits to your own posts, edits to community wiki posts after reaching 100 rep, edits after reaching 2000 rep).